# url_launcher doesn't launch download android flutter

Tags: android, flutter, webview, package, url-launcher

[image]

I'm developing a Flutter application that uses the url_launcher package to download files from URLs. However, I'm experiencing an issue where the url_launcher doesn't launch downloads on Android. Instead, it just opens the URL in a browser window without initiating the download. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?"

this is my code

```
    Future<void> _fetchDownloadUrl() async {
    String enteredUrl = _videoUrl.trim();
    RegExp urlRegex = RegExp(r'https?://(?:www\.)?WEBSITE\.com/.*');

    if (enteredUrl.isEmpty) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 27, 11),
          content: Text("Please enter a valid link"),
        ),
      );
    } else if (!urlRegex.hasMatch(enteredUrl)) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 27, 11),
          content: Text("Please enter a tiktok link"),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isRedirecting = true;
      });
      var headers = {
        'X-Rapidapi-Key': 'API KEY',
        'X-Rapidapi-Host': 'API HOST',
      };
     
      var url =
          'API URL/?url=$_videoUrl';
      
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers);

      var responseData = await jsonDecode(response.body);
      var noWatermarkUrl = await responseData["data"]["play"];
     

      launchUrl(Uri.parse(noWatermarkUrl));
      setState(() {
        isRedirecting = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have granted this necessary permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: i granted the permission but it still not downloading

Comment: Check if the URL you are trying to launch is correct and accessible. You can try launching a different URL to see if the issue is with the URL you are using.